# check multiple rows and return if all match

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like so:

products:

```
id  name       description
1   book book  desc
2   tea tea    desc
3   glasses    glasses desc
```

product_attributes

```
product_id    attribute_id
1             2
2             7
2             8
3             2
3             7
3             9
3             10
1             2
1             5
1             7
```

I also have two variables called `$pid` which holds product ids and has a value of `2,3,1` AND `$search_ids` which holds attribute ids and has a value of `7,8`

I want result to return ONLY if one id from `product_id` is in rows with all values from `$search_ids`

In this specific case I would expect it to return only `tea` , because only tea's id is in rows with all values from `$search_ids` (7 and 8).

I tried the following but it returns all 3 products and then again tea twice, so I get like 5 results. I understand its logic, but don't know how to change it do do what I want.

```
$q = "SELECT p.name FROM products AS p, product_attributes AS pa WHERE p.id = pa.product_id AND pa.product_id IN ($pid) AND pa.attribute_id IN ($search_ids)";
```

With the query above, I get the following:

```
Tea
glasses
Book
Tea
Tea
```

Comment: Try: $q = "SELECT p.name FROM products p inner join product_attributes pa ON p.id = pa.product_id  WHERE pa.product_id IN ($pid) AND pa.attribute_id IN ($search_ids)";

Comment: I get the exact same result as with my query.

Comment: Well it's kinda easy to understand why he prints it, you are printing all the possible combinations between (2,3,1) and (7,8) which are 5 possibilities in your case..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it returns such values, because it will give you a name as long as $search_ids contain any of searched ids. That's how SQL "IN" works.

Try following (silly and probably not too optimal) solution:

Helper variable:

```
$search_ids_size = count($search_ids);
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.name) FROM products AS p, product_attributes AS pa 
  WHERE p.id = pa.product_id 
     AND p.id IN ($pid)
     AND (SELECT count(*) FROM product_attributes WHERE product_id = p.id 
          AND attribute_id IN ($search_ids)) = $search_ids_size;
```

I tested it on your dataset and it works, although there is probably a simpler solution for this.